# Xcode is not calling asp.net webservice

Tags: objective-c, xcode, oracle, ora-00936

I have oracle database and using webservice i want to insert some records in to it
So i created webservice in asp.net as follows

```
 public bool PickPill(string Me_id, string Mem_device_id, string Test_datetime, string Creation_id, string PillBayNo)
    {
        string Hed_seq_id = Hed_seq_Id();
        bool ResultHED = InsHealthEData(Hed_seq_id, Mem_device_id, Me_id, Test_datetime, Creation_id);
        bool ResultHET = InsHealthETest(Hed_seq_id, PillBayNo, Test_datetime, Creation_id);

        if (ResultHED == ResultHET == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
```

this function did all data insertion trick for me i tested this service on the local mechine with ip address 
http:72.44.151.178/PickPillService.asmx
then,
I see an example on how to attach asp.net web service to iphone apps
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43209/0/page/4
then i created simillar code in xcode which has 2 files

1. ConsumePillServiceViewController.m
2. ConsumePillServiceViewController.h file

Now,
Using Designer of xcode i created 5 textboxes(Me_id,Mem_device_id,Test_datetime,Creation_id,PillBayNo) with all parameters hardcode as our service demands 
then modify my  ConsumePillServiceViewController.h file as follows

```
@interface ConsumePillServiceViewController : UIViewController {
 //---outlets---
  IBOutlet UITextField *Me_id;
  IBOutlet UITextField *Mem_device_id;
  IBOutlet UITextField *Test_datetime;
  IBOutlet UITextField *Creation_id;
  IBOutlet UITextField *PillBayNo;
 //---web service access---
    NSMutableData *webData;
    NSMutableString *soapResults;
    NSURLConnection *conn;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *Me_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *Mem_device_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *Test_datetime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *Creation_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *PillBayNo;
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;
@end

and 
ConsumePillServiceViewController.m as follows

#import "ConsumePillServiceViewController.h"

@implementation ConsumePillServiceViewController
@synthesize Me_id;
@synthesize Mem_device_id;
@synthesize Test_datetime;
@synthesize Creation_id;
@synthesize PillBayNo;

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
NSString *soapMsg = 
 @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
 "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
 "<soap:Body>"
"<PickPill xml1ns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">";
NSString *smMe_id=
[soapMsg stringByAppendingString:
[NSString stringWithFormat:
@"<Me_id>%@</Me_id>",Me_id.text]];

 NSString *smMem_device_id=
 [smMe_id stringByAppendingString:
[NSString stringWithFormat:
 @"<Mem_device_id>%@</Mem_device_id>",Mem_device_id.text]];

NSString *smTest_datetime=
 [smMem_device_id stringByAppendingString:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:
  @"<Test_datetime>%@</Test_datetime>",Test_datetime.text]];

NSString *smCreation_id=
 [smTest_datetime stringByAppendingString:
[NSString stringWithFormat:
 @"<Creation_id>%@</Creation_id>",Creation_id.text]];

NSString *smPillBayNo=
 [smCreation_id stringByAppendingString:
[NSString stringWithFormat:
 @"<PillBayNo>%@</PillBayNo>",PillBayNo.text]];

NSString *smRestMsg=
 [smPillBayNo stringByAppendingString:
@"</PickPill>"
"</soap:Body>" "</soap:Envelope>"];

 soapMsg=smRestMsg;

 //---print it to the Debugger Console for verification---
 NSLog(soapMsg);


 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:   //create a URL load request object using instances :
      @"http://72.44.151.178/PickPillService.asmx"];//of the NSMutableURLRequest and NSURL objects
 NSMutableURLRequest *req = 
 [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];



 //opulate the request object with the various headers, such as Content-Type, SOAPAction, and Content-Length. 
 //You also set the HTTP method and HTTP body
 NSString *msgLength = 
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];
 [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8"  
forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [req addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/PickPill" 
forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
 [req addValue:msgLength 
forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 //---set the HTTP method and body---
 [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [req setHTTPBody: [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



 conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self]; //establish the connection with the web service, 
 if (conn) {  //you use the NSURLConnection class together with the request object just created
  webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];//webData object use to receive incoming data from the web service
 }    

}//End of button clicked event





-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection //Recive response
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response {
 [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection //Repeative call method and append data to webData
 didReceiveData:(NSData *) data {
 [webData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection//If error occure error should be displayed  
  didFailWithError:(NSError *) error {
 [webData release];
    [connection release];
}


-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] 
                        initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] 
                        length:[webData length] 
                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //---shows the XML---
    NSLog(theXML);

    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

 // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
 // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
 [Me_id release];
 [Creation_id release];
 [Mem_device_id release];
 [Test_datetime release];
 [PillBayNo release];
    [soapResults release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I did all things as shown in the website and when i built application it successfully built 
but in the debuggin window i see

```
(gdb) continue
2010-03-17 09:09:54.595 ConsumePillService[6546:20b] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><PickPill xml1ns="http://tempuri.org/"><Me_id>A00000004303</Me_id><Mem_device_id>1011</Mem_device_id><Test_datetime>03/13/2010 07:34:38</Test_datetime><Creation_id>Hboxdata</Creation_id><PillBayNo>2</PillBayNo></PickPill></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
(gdb) continue
(gdb) continue
(gdb) continue
2010-03-17 09:10:05.411 ConsumePillService[6546:20b] DONE. Received Bytes: 476
2010-03-17 09:10:05.412 ConsumePillService[6546:20b] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; One or more errors occurred during processing of command.

ORA-00936: missing expression</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

It should return me true if all things are ok
What is this ORA-00936 error all about

as it is not releted with webservice

Please help me solving this problem

Thanks in advance,
Vaibhav Deshpande

Comment: ORA-00936 is from Oracle SQL saying the command was wrong so we need to know what the SQL command your asp.net sent to oracle

Comment: As Mark mentions, obviously all things are NOT okay.  There is some problem executing the insert command in Oracle.  You will need to show us the insert query you are using in order for us to help.